# How do I make a button in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I coded

```
<a class="link,  btn"(styles that I made) href="">About me</a>
```

But I don't know what to put in the href. 
Can anyone help? 
Thanks!

Comment: What is your code so far? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to get my screen go downwards to the about me section

Comment: My whole code is at home but when I'll come back home I'll send it all if needed

Comment: Then put `href="#aboutme"` assuming one of the elements in your about me section (for example the title), has `id="aboutme"`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up for me!

Answer (score 0):

html buttons don't really have hrefs. They are usually within a form and the form has the href in it. If you don't have a form and you just want the 'look' of a button you can use this code:

```
<style>.button { background: grey; color: black; }</style>
```

then in the body where you want your link

```
<a href="#idtogoto" class="button">Oh yeah baby!</a>
```

..... down the page somewhere

you can also use (s)

Just keep in mind you can only have one unique id per page. Dont give two elements the same id.

The link will now 'jump' down the page to the 'anchor'

You can use sites like this one to generate prettier buttons than that one! http://css3buttongenerator.com/

If you need clarification just ask, good luck!

Comment: I'd love some clarifications I just intend it to work as a button the guy above answered my question,  thanks anyway!